# How do I identify a computer on network?

Tags: c#, networking, router

I have a network with many devices. How do I identify that an IP/MAC acquired from an ARP table belongs to a computer, and not a networking device (router/switch etc)?

I'm primary using C#, but any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Network devices are computers, albeit simple ones. Your router is likely a low powered Linux computer that has a simple web server for admin access and `iptables` running. Explain what you want to do with this information once you have your list of "computers" and we may be able to give you a better way to generate the correct list.

Comment: I am using a local database of MACs to identify different network devices without internet connectivity. Unfortunately there are thousands of different Motherboard and NIC manufactorers, and adding them all would be a lot of trouble.

Comment: If you are doing something with MAC address you can have your application download the vendor list from http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt then parse out what you need. I do this with one of my network scanners.

Comment: While it is indeed a good idea, it could be rather confusing. If you take an Asus computer, it might have a Gigabyte NIC, and thus show up as a Gigabyte Device, even though it is an Asus Computer.

Comment: The computers I am trying to identify would all be Windows computers. Would I be able to make a NetBIOS scan?